# How to clear field after submittion in React with useState

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on a Mernstack application, everything in my application is working well except the input field that doesn't clear after submission.

my Component

`const [comments, setCommentData] = useState([]);`

```
const onSubmit = useCallback(
  (e) => {
   e && e.preventDefault();
  
  axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost:9000/events/" +
        props.match.params.id +
        "/eventcomment",
      { name: name, description: eventDescription }
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("response", response.data.eventcomments);
      onPageLoad();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
[props.match.params.id, name, eventDescription]
);
```

I tried doing this but it didn't work.

`setCommentData("");`

Comment: You are not working in controlled components in react most probably. In your case, you can do something like e.target.value = "", after the api call

Comment: If @simbathesailor is right, the 'Reactest' way to do it would be through a `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

The initial state is `[]`, so you should restore it to the same initial content:

```
setCommentData([]);
```